# Rails - Attachments for an email appear at the top of the email and not the bottom

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Anyone know why rails, places attachments at the top of the email and not the bottom?

Mac Mail, and the Iphone for example show the attachments at the top of the email and not at the bottom, which is very strange.

My user_mailer.rb looks like this:

```
def error_email
    attachments['message.html'] = {:mime_type => 'text/html', :content => message_text }

    mail(:to => @message_from, :subject => 'reason whyxxxx')
end
```

How can I get the attachment at the bottom of the email msg?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into this before. A quick fix is to do this in your mailer method to reverse the order of the email parts.

```
message = mail(:to => @message_from, :subject => 'reason whyxxxx')
message.parts.reverse!
```

Comment: Any ideas on why this happens? also, any way to specifically set the parts. so it's more solid?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the parts whichever way you want like this:

```
body.set_sort_order(order)
body.sort_parts!
```

-- where `order` defaults to `['text/plain', 'text/enriched', 'text/html', 'multipart/alternative']`.

However this sorts on content type, as far as I can tell, so if your attachment has the same content type as the text part it won't make any difference.